# Standard matrix of Rotation and Reflection

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been fuzzy on this transformation stuff and am practicing for an upcoming test.

```
 Find the standard matrix: counterclockwise rotation through 60 degrees, followed by a reflection in the line y=x
```

I am not exactly sure how to do this. My textbook gives an example of how to find the standard matrix of a rotation by a formula. I also know that the standard matrix of a reflection of the line y=x is {{0,1},{1,0}}. But, I don't really know how to tackle this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  The column vectors of the linear transformation matrix will be wherever the standard basis vectors are mapped to.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know how I should put that statement in action

Comment: `where the standard basis vectors are mapped to.` What does this mean?

Comment: The vector $<1, 0>$, our first standard basis vector, gets rotated $60$ degrees, so it becomes $<.5, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}>$.  Next, it gets reflected over the line $y=x$.  In other words, the $x$ coordinate becomes the $y$-coordinate and vice versa.  So we get $<\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, .5>$.  This is therefore the first column vector in our matrix.  For the second column in our matrix, you'll have to find where the second standard basis vector, $<0, 1>$, gets mapped to.

Comment: So the other column vector should be <0.5, sqrt(3)/2>, right?

Comment: I have used your method and the matrix should be {{sqrt(3)/2,0.5},{0.5,sqrt(3)/2}}

Comment: That second basis vector is first rotated into the second quadrant, so there should be a negative sign somewhere in there I believe.  But you certainly have the right idea!